# How to read all the elements of array at once and determine what already exists in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

> Use a one-dimensional array to solve the following problem: 
>   Write an application that inputs five numbers, each between 10 and 100, inclusive. As each number is read, display it only if it’s not a duplicate of a number already read. Provide for the “worst case,” in which all five numbers are different. Use the smallest possible array to solve this problem. Display the complete set of unique values input after the user enters each new value.

My program is running fine for the most part. The only problem I'm facing is when i input the second element of the array to check when the first one is asked to input, it outputs "the number is not in the array". Even though the number is in the array. Please go easy on me because i am pretty naive with programming.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DuplicateElimination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // the variable to read the number
        int number = 0;

        // the array with the elements needed to be checked
        int [] array = {12, 33, 54, 90, 100, 1};

        // for loop to ask the question if the number is in the array.
        for(int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++ )
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a number to check: ");
            number = input.nextInt();

            if (number == array[counter])
                System.out.printf("The number %d is already in the array.\n\n", array[counter]);


            else
                System.out.printf("The number %d is not in the array.\n\n", number);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S this is not a homework I'm just doing it to keep me in practice.

Comment: The array is already full, you've created it with 5 entries. Are you sure this isn't homework? Because your code really doesn't match your problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

Using this condition:

```
if (number == array[counter])
```

You're evaluating if the current value of `number` is equals to a single value inside the `array`. In order to evaluate if the value of `number` is stored in `array` is to check all the values inside `array`. Here's an example of how to achieve it:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int j = 0; j < currentSizeOfArray; j++) {
    if (number == array[j]) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    //do something
}
```

Another hint to solve your homework: use a `while` loop to read the data, not a `for` loop. Also, have a temporal variable that maintains the current number of elements in the array, which **is not** the same as the length of the array.